# htaccess RewriteRule works but browser does not display friendly URL

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I want to simply have the URL:

example.com/connect/admin/create

Redirect to:

example.com/connect/admin/create.php

I have the code below on the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^connect/admin/create$ http://example.com/connect/admin/create.php [R=301,L,NE]
```

And it redirects properly. The issue is that the browser now displays

example.com/connect/admin/create.php

When I still want it to display:

```
example.com/connect/admin/create
```

Do I need to add something else to .htaccess?

Thank you

Comment: That's because you have a hard redirect via `R=301`. If you don't want it to redirect the browser, just remove that and it will rewrite silently. Also, you need to remove the `http://example.com/`

Comment: Per your reply, I change the code to: RewriteRule ^connect/admin/create$ /connect/admin/create.php [L,NE] and the result is still the same.

Comment: You also need to remove the leading `/` from `/connect/admin/create.php` An absolute path will cause it to attempt a redirect.

Comment: It actually had been cached in the browser for whatever reason. I cleared the cache and it worked.

Comment: Ok, I'll place it below as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original rewrite rule contains an explicit redirect via `R=301`. That flag will need to be removed. Secondly, the right-side of the `RewriteRule` (the target) include `http://example.com/` which will also force a browser redirection implicitly.  Instead, use just the relative path on the right side:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^connect/admin/create$ connect/admin/create.php [L,NE]
```

This can be done in a more generic way if you will also have additional actions inside `connect/admin` from which you'd like to strip the `.php`:

```
# Capture the action into $1 and pass it to the redirect target.
RewriteRule ^connect/admin/([^/.]+)/?$ connect/admin/$1.php [L,NE]
```